# Curve is not defined on a function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

We have the following complex curves and the function $$f(z) = z^{-1/2}$$
Where $z$ is a complex number.

We want to integrate f on the above curves, so on $K_1, K_2,K_3$.
In lectures we said that the curves $K_2$ and $K_1$ don't exist for this function, because there it isn't defined.  Can somebody show why is that so? Why those two curves aren't defined there?

Comment: Curves do not exist for, or on, a function, they are there in the plane. It’s not clear what your instructor was trying to say. You have three directed arcs, all  going upwards from $-2i$ to $2i$. All are perfectly well defined. On each of the semicircular arcs, the function has an unambiguous definition, but I would say that it can’t be defined as a differentiable function on the vertical arc. Are you sure you have the arrows going in the right direction?

Comment: @Lubin The topic that we talked about in the lectures was that we can't integrate that function on $K_1$ and $K_2$. (And the instructor written down that it's because they are not defined on $f$. I dont know what he was really trying to say). I will edit the question, so that it is known that we want to integrate it.

Comment: The function $\sqrt(z)$ for complex $z$ has to have a branch cut somewhere. It would seem the choice of branch cut might cut through both the origin on $K_1$ and the point $2$ on $K_2.$ If this is what your professor means it should be said to the students.